# Sphinx starts chapter numbering from 0 in LaTeX output

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, python-sphinx

I'm generating a PDF document With Sphinx using latex.

```
======================
RX-loader instructions
======================

Program
=======
```

However this generates

> 0.1 RX-loader instructions
>   0.1.1 Program

How do I make the numbering start with 1?

Edit:
My index.rst looks like this

```
#######################
RX-loader documentation
#######################

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   rx-loader
```

My problem seems to be that the numbering takes "RX-loader documentation" as chapter 0 and always writes the chapters the section numbers.

Comment: Try and use a different markdown strategy (see [Headers](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#headers)); it seems like the double `===` is mistaken for a single one, resulting in it being a `\section` rather than a `\chapter`.

Comment: I tried to replace === with *** but still with the same result.

Comment: If you followed exactly the suggestion in the linked post and it didn't solve your problem, I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: Well I gave up, and changed to asciidoc. I do not like that asciidoctor uses Ruby, but it solved my task.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be a dirty trick but it results in the desired pdf behaviour on Sphinx 1.6.7 (In html the first line must be removed):

```
Filler text
======================
RX-loader instructions
======================

Program 1
---------
Program 2
---------
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That didn't have any effect on my document.

Comment: Which sphinx & python versions are you using? Are you sure you chose reStructuredText (.rst) in your `conf.py` and not Markdown (.md) text?

Comment: sphinx-build 1.8.5
both md and rst is enabled in conf.py

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong, for me it worked. Maybe if you are using Windows that could be it as I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file, add a preamble to the latex_elements dictionary, like this:

```
latex_elements = {
'preamble': r'''
    \counterwithout{section}{chapter}
    '''
}
```